# SpringBoot Ant Matchers terminates at DefaultSecurityFilterChain [Creating filter chain]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I encountered a problem here that I could not solve below is my code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
}

private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
        "/css/**",
        "/images/**",
        "/js/**",
        "/",
        "/myaccount"
};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{   

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS)
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
        .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
        .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception{
    authentication.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

}
```

I tried a lot of things I tried disabling security in application.properties.
when I removed this bit of code from the method .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated(); the program continues a little further and throws another exception suggesting to put hasRole() after the antMatchers.
Below is my error code

```
 2018-10-18 09:13:21.471  INFO 2660 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
 2018-10-18 09:13:21.476  INFO 2660 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
 2018-10-18 09:13:21.578  INFO 2660 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
 2018-10-18 09:13:21.925  INFO 2660 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 Hibernate: alter table user_role add constraint FKa68196081fvovjhkek5m97n3y foreign key (role_id) references role (role_id)
 Hibernate: alter table user_role add constraint FK859n2jvi8ivhui0rl0esws6o foreign key (user_id) references user (id)
 2018-10-18 09:13:23.595  INFO 2660 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
 2018-10-18 09:13:25.371  INFO 2660 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@611b35d6, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2047981, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@456f7d9e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@19e21f89, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1af4955e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6f31df32, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@552cede7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@ee21292, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2282400e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@8f40022, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@c8f97a7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7d0100ea]
```

Comment: I think problem is not in configuration rather it is in your table structure. I think dropping user_role table will solve the issue. Column type mismatch in entity class and table structure.

Comment: that didn't work sir

Comment: I don't see any error. `INFO` level is not an error